# How to calculate O(log n) in big O notation?

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

I know that `O(log n)` refers to an iterative reduction by a fixed ratio of the problem set `N` (in big O notation), but how do i actually calculate it to see how many iterations an algorithm with a `log N` complexity would have to preform on the problem set `N` before it is done (has one element left)?

Comment: O(log n) can result from iterative reduction in problem size by any fixed ratio, not just halving.

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Hmm... True... fixed the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You don't calculate the exact number of iterations with BigO.

You can "derive" BigO when you have exact formula for number of iterations.

BigO just gives information how the number iterations grows with growing N, and only for "big" N.

Nothing more, nothing less. With this you can draw conclusions how much more operations/time will the algorithm take if you have some sample runs.

Comment: True, and thank you for the answer. As you said, in the case where you know the exact proportion that the problem set is reduced by, you can derive it, but is there a more efficient way of doing so than running the calculation in a while loop, like: while(N > 1){ N=N/2} or something of that nature? in other words, is there a calculation you could do on a calculator, given the exact reduction in problem set for each iteration, to compute exactly how many iteration are required? thanks.

Comment: No no, you don't do any loops. You transform loops into summations and other mathematical formulas, and then, yes you can calculate the number of operations. For example, you have an INSERT operation that takes `O(log SIZE)` to complete on a data structure for example addition of element. And you have algorithm that needs to construct such data structure from N element, and you decide to insert them one by one you would have `Sum over i from 0 to N-1: O(INSERT(i))` => `Sum over i from 0 to N-1: O(log(i))` => from O properties you can "take it outside" `O( Sum over i from 0 to N-1: log(i) )`.

Answer (score 1):

Expressed in the words of Tim Roughgarden at his courses on algorithms:

> The big-Oh notation tries to provide a sweet spot for high level algorithm reasoning

That means it is intended to describe the relation between the algorithm time execution and the size of its input avoiding dependencies on the system architecture, programming language or chosen compiler.

Imagine that big-Oh notation could provide the exact execution time, that would mean that for any algorithm, for which you know its big-Oh time complexity function, you could predict how would it behave on any machine whatsoever.

On the other hand, it is centered on asymptotic behaviour. That is, its description is more accurate for big `n` values (that is why lower order terms of your algorithm time function are ignored in big-Oh notation). It can reasoned that low `n` values do not demand you to push foward trying to improve your algorithm performance.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation only shows an order of magnitude - not the actual number of operations that algorithm would perform. If you need to calculate exact number of loop iterations or elementary operations, you have to do it by hand. However in most practical purposes exact number is irrelevant - `O(log n)` tells you that num. of operations will raise logarythmically with a raise of `n`

Answer (score 0):

From big O notation you can't tell precisely how many iteration will the algorithm do, it's just estimation. That means with small numbers the different between the log(n) and actual number of iterations could be differentiate significantly but the closer you get to infinity the different less significant.

Answer (score 0):

If you make some assumptions, you can estimate the time up to a constant factor. The big assumption is that the limiting behavior as the size tends to infinity is the same as the actual behavior for the problem sizes you care about.

Under that assumption, the upper bound on the time for a size `N` problem is `C*log(N)` for some constant `C`. The constant will change depending on the base you use for calculating the logarithm. The base does not matter as long as you are consistent about it. If you have the measured time for one size, you can estimate `C` and use that to guesstimate the time for a different size.

For example, suppose a size 100 problem takes 20 seconds. Using common logarithms, `C` is 10. (The common log of 100 is 2). That suggests a size 1000 problem might take about 30 seconds, because the common log of 1000 is 3.

However, this is very rough. The approach is most useful for estimating whether an algorithm might be usable for a large problem. In that sort of situation, you also have to pay attention to memory size. Generally, setting up a problem will be at least linear in size, so its cost will grow faster than an `O(log N)` operation.